# The window I am creating is jumping all around my screen, why?

Tags: javascript

hopefully I explain this decently. I am new to explicitly using the Browser Object Model. My program is supposed to create a new window then move the window (clockwise) around the edge of the screen. I believe something is off with the timing because when I run it, the window starts moving to the right across the top of the screen then speeds up to the point where it is just bouncing all over the place. Here is what I have:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;
        var moveX = true;
        var moveY = false;
        var aWindow;
        var timer;
        function openWindow(){
            aWindow = window.open("", "", "width=400, height=200");
            aWindow.document.write("This is my new window");
        }

        function closeWindow(){
            if(aWindow){
                aWindow.close();
            }
        }


        function moveWindow(){
            if(aWindow){
                if(moveX){
                    x += 100;
                }
                if(moveY){
                    y += 100;
                }
                if(x == 1200){
                    moveX = false;
                    moveY = true;
                    x *= -1;        //Sets up x so it will move back across the screen backwards
                }
                if(y == 700){
                    moveX = true;
                    moveY = false;
                    y *= -1;        //Sets up y so it will move back up the screen
                }
                aWindow.moveTo(x, y);
                timer = setInterval(moveWindow, 1000)
            }
        }

        function stopMove(){
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="openWindow();">Open</button>
    <button onclick="closeWindow();">Close</button>
    <button onclick="moveWindow();">Move</button>
    <button onclick="stopMove();">Stop moving</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This crashed my macOS. Thank you! 

Comment: Look into using setTimeout instead of setInterval - see [this article](https://dev.to/akanksha_9560/why-not-to-use-setinterval--2na9) and [this](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-polling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that each time you call `moveWindow`, it sets another timer interval to run itself. So the number of `moveWindow` calls keeps multiplying.

You should only use `setInterval` once, probably in its own `startMoving` function.

You can replace the `onclick="moveWindow()"` for the move button with a `onclick=startMoving()` function to call `setInterval` **once**.